# how does the mapper element used in mappers element in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

Recently, i read a mybatis project using a special mappers configuration, like this:

```
<mapper resource="com/demo/mapper/User-70kocDJShTI4.static" />
```

I can not figure out how this is used. Can someone help me out?

======================================================================

[EDIT]

It is my fault not finding the static file in correct directory.
It finally shows that the static files are also xml format, however with
a different suffix.

Answer (score 0):

This is the name of the file containing a *mapper* (that is, the file containing the various `select`, `insert`, et al mapper items) to be used in the *mapper* config xml file, assuming that this is surrounded by `<mappers></mappers>` tags within `<configuration></configuration>` tags.

Generally this would be an *xml* file, but it appears in this case the file's got an unusual name. I strongly suspect that while its extension is **.static**, it's still actually an *xml* file.

See the [Mybatis doc](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) for more info on the config xml.